# FormData sending blank file field when appending files via drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, drag-and-drop

I have a photo upload page that allows drag and drop functionality.

The form is here:

```html
<form id="Upload" method="post" action="sessionapi/UserPicture/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input class="box__file" type="file" name="files[]" id="file" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
  <input type="hidden" name="UserPictureReferenceID" value="<%=mPictureGalleryCvm.UserPictureReference.UserPictureReferenceID%>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="UserPictureReferenceType" value="<%=mPictureGalleryCvm.UserPictureReference.UserPictureReferenceType%>" />
  <div id="photoUploadArea" class="hide">
    <div id="photoDropArea">
      <h2>Add Up to 10 photos</h2>
      <p class="subTitle">Your file must be a JPEG, PNG, or GIF</p>
      <p><img src="img/mascotLeftNoResults.png" /></p>
      <h3>Drag and Drop Photos Here</h3>
      <div class="hr-line">
         <h3><span>OR</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div id="photoUploadButton">
        <input id="files" class="fileUploadInput hide" type="file" multiple="">
        <button class="fileBrowserButton" type="submit" value="submit"><span>Browse Files</span></button>
  <script>
      $('.fileBrowserButton').on('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#file").click();
      })
  </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The function to send the data via AJAX is here:

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var ajaxData = new FormData($form.get(0)),
        $input = $form.find('input[type="file"]'),
        files;
    if (evt.type == 'change') files = evt.target.files;
    else files = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) { //Loop through selected images
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) { //check file is an image
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                if (files && evt.type != 'change') {
                    $.each(files, function (i, file) { //problem is here
                        ajaxData.append($input.attr('name'), file);
                    });
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'sessionapi/UserPicture/Upload',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: ajaxData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                })
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
```

The problem with the code is with the area in the JS code:

```js
$.each(files, function (i, file) {
    ajaxData.append($input.attr('name'), file);
});
```

ajaxData appends a file input to FormData for the new file that was dragged in. However, when the file is submitted via ajax, it sends the blank "file" input already in the form. I need to send all fields minus the blank file field on drag and drop. How do I do this?

Comment: did you try to add the html form attribute to fileinput? if you specify a different form name, it should be ignored by this one.

Comment: Not sure I follow you.

Comment: every element in a form is assigned by default to the containing form, but you can override that by manually setting the form attribute of the element itself.

Comment: <input id="files" form="someRandomName" ... >

Comment: That did work. I am changing the form attr of the input dynamically when a file is dragged in. Thank you.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add the html form attribute to fileinput? if you specify a different form name, it should be ignored by this one.

```
<input id="files" form="someRandomName" ... >
```

EDIT:

Yes, you can also remove the input if it doesn't take the form attribute.

Comment: I fixed the issue by removing the input before establishing the FormData Object if a photo is being dropped into the area. However, your response led me down the right path. If you append your answer to reflect my solution ill mark it as correct.